# Fontello icons don't work in my iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, uifont

I have been trying to add fontello icons to my app. I have followed all the instructions. I add the .ttf file to my project, added a 'Fonts provided by application' row to my info.plist file, added the fontello.ttf file as item0, changed the label font to fontello and the text to unicode. When I run the code in the simulator, instead of the icons, I just get a square with a question mark in it. Am I missing something?
I got no errors in the console. I use xcode 7.3 and swift 2. 
I am new to iOS development and have been stuck with this for a while. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you install the font in your Mac's Font Book?

Comment: Yes, I installed it.

Answer (score 1):

Install the fontello font with cocoapods

https://cocoapods.org/pods/Fontello-Swift